# Dialog with minimal DateFormat logic not showing on client's phone

Tags: flutter

I understand this question is not very high quality, but there is unfortunately not much I know. Thank you for understanding and please feel free to ask me any questions.

I have a button, that on press shows a dialog. That dialog is extremely simple and has very minimal logic, yet it doesn't show on my client's phone.

I have tried on many android emulators and ALL IOS simulators, and it works perfectly. I am not getting any errors on Crashlytics from the client's phone.

Notes:

- tourDays is never null.
- The app has several other animatedDialogs and they all work fine.
- Client lives in Switzerland, and their phone is iPhone 12 mini running IOS 14.4.2 in German.
- When they press the button, nothing happens at all.
- Translation files are working great.
- As you can see, the dialog has minimal logic, which is driving me crazy. Could there be a problem with my usage of the DateFormat class? I have changed the region and language of my iPhone to match his but the issue still doesn't occur on my phone :/

Here is the button's onPressed code:

```
final int numberOfDays =
                              controller.tour.tourDays!.length;
                          showAnimatedDialog(
                            context: context,
                            child: Dialog(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                              insetPadding:
                                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: Wrap(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                                    runSpacing: 30,
                                    children: List.generate(numberOfDays,
                                        (calendarIndex) {
                                      final tempDate = controller
                                          .tour.startDate!
                                          .add(Duration(days: calendarIndex));
                                      return InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          pageController
                                              .jumpToPage(calendarIndex);
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          decoration: index == calendarIndex
                                              ? BoxDecoration(
                                                  border: Border.all(
                                                    color: Constants.lightPink,
                                                    width: 2,
                                                  ),
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(8))
                                              : BoxDecoration(),
                                          width: (MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                      .size
                                                      .width -
                                                  MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                      .viewInsets
                                                      .left -
                                                  MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                      .viewInsets
                                                      .right -
                                                  64) /
                                              3,
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                controller
                                                    .getDayOfWeek(controller
                                                            .tour
                                                            .startDate!
                                                            .weekday +
                                                        calendarIndex)
                                                    .tr()
                                                    .substring(0, 2),
                                                style: Constants.boldMediumStyle
                                                    .apply(
                                                        color: Constants
                                                            .lightPink),
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                  tempDate.day.toString() +
                                                      '. ' +
                                                      DateFormat('MMMM')
                                                          .format(DateTime
                                                              .fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                                                                  tempDate
                                                                      .millisecondsSinceEpoch))
                                                          .toLowerCase()
                                                          .tr()
                                                          .substring(0, 3) +
                                                      ' ' +
                                                      tempDate.year
                                                          .toString()
                                                          .substring(2, 4),
                                                  style: Constants
                                                      .regularSmallStyle
                                                      .apply(
                                                    color: Constants.lightPink,
                                                    fontSizeDelta: -3,
                                                  )),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
```

Here is the getDayOfWeek method:

```
String getDayOfWeek(int weekDay) {
    weekDay = weekDay % 7;
    String nameOfDay;
    switch (weekDay) {
      case 0:
        nameOfDay = 'sunday';
        break;
      case 1:
        nameOfDay = 'monday';
        break;
      case 2:
        nameOfDay = 'tuesday';
        break;
      case 3:
        nameOfDay = 'wednesday';
        break;
      case 4:
        nameOfDay = 'thursday';
        break;
      case 5:
        nameOfDay = 'friday';
        break;
      case 6:
        nameOfDay = 'saturday';
        break;
      default:
        nameOfDay = 'NA';
        break;
    }
    return nameOfDay;
  }
```

Here's how it should look:
[image: Dialog image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. The problem was with this line

```
DateFormat('MMMM')
.format(DateTime
.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
tempDate
.millisecondsSinceEpoch))
.toLowerCase()
.tr()
.substring(0, 3)
```

It was throwing a `Invalid argument(s): Invalid locale "gsw_CH"`

Turns out that DateFormat class does not support the Swiss Deutsch (gsw_CH) locale. Forced it to English (as I already do translations on my app) and it worked. Very Frustrating bug.

Changed `DateFormat('MMMM')` to `DateFormat('MMMM', 'en')`